# analogs of socket in python

Tags: python, sockets

Can you advise me on the analogs of the socket library on Python? The task is this, I need to write a very simple script with which I could execute remote commands in cmd windows. I know how this can be implemented using the socket library, but I would like to know if there are any other libraries for such a case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets is a low level mechanism by which two systems can communicate each other. Your OS provides this mechanism, there's no analogs.

Next examples come from the application layer and they work with sockets in their lower communication layers: a socket open by your http server, usually 80 or 443 or a websocket open by your browser to communicate with your server. Or the DNS query that your browser executes when tries to resolve a domain name, also works with sockets between your PC and the DNS server.